# Dont allow null or undefined with useState and TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

I'm adding TypeScript types to React's useState hook.

```
const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState<"checked" | un-checked">(null);
```

Is it possible to only allow the `checked` and `un-checked` values and not `null` or `undefined` so that the code above would error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable `"strictNullChecks": true` in your `tsconfig.json`

> Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   '"checked" | "un-checked" | (() => "checked" | "un-checked")'.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html